# How can I put my custom URLs to SOLR results

Tags: solr

I am trying to index my database data with SOLR and I am successfully indexed it.

What I need is:

- I need to put URLs with every results.
- The URLs for each result item will be different.
- Each result item need to append its item_id (which is available as a field) with its URL.

I am very new to SOLR configurations and SOLR query, so please help to implement a better search result XML.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store URL in an additional field (stored=true indexed=false) and then simply retrieve it when you're searching.

Even better if you can compose URLs yourself (if they differ only in ID/primary key) by appending document ID to some fixed URL, that's certainly a better way to go.
That would include altering your page which displays search results.

What kind of application is your Solr integrated with?
Where are those documents of yours stored? In a db? How do you get to them through your application?

Comment: Can you answer the questions first, so I can give you better example?

Comment: SOLR is integrating with a rails application. The data is stored in a MySQL DB and iam connecting solr using mysql JDBC.

Comment: OK, so you have fields url & idem_id stored in solr. Retrieve them when you search (http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fl) and glue them together in ruby to form a URL.

Comment: I did like that. I am just checking if there any other options (settings) available in solr to set URL with each search results.

Comment: Hard way to do things in SOLR. No easy ways to implement my need. I done the hard way and implemented. Thanks all for your comments and valuable time.